# Order of wall tiling with baseboards in bathroom

Tags: baseboard, tiling

What is the order of tiling bathroom walls when installing baseboards also. Do I tile the wall first and then add the baseboard or would it make sense to install baseboard first and then add the wall tiles.

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking; would you perhaps add a diagram?

Comment: Sorry. I’ve reworded it... hope it makes more sense now. Essentially I have to tile a wall but also I need to ad baseboards. it seems to make sense to add the baseboards first and then tile the wall, but checking to see if any other views on this..

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm no pro, but I'm *guessing* the baseboard goes on last.